# Using std::unique_ptr in object cache

Tags: c++, caching, collections, c++17, std

I am trying to convert some legacy code to C++17(ish).

I have some objects which have multiple versions - each version has the same members, but different sizes.
I have a factory class which caches objects as they are created and continues to return the same object on future requests.

This all worked great with C pointers (albeit not 'safe').   Using the unique_ptr template is giving me grief due to the Ownership.

I want the factory to have full ownership and control of the pointers and the caller to just access the object it is given  (originally that was through an Object*)

I have tried making the factory function return a unique_ptr and also a reference.   Each has its own issues.

Getting the unique_ptr returned fails for several reasons and my understanding is the caller then posses ownership so the cache no longer can get to the object.

I made the factory function work with a ref return, but the caller has issues getting the ref into a variable  (see code).

Here is the code on Compiler Explorer:  https://godbolt.org/z/M9Gr9j

I am sorry the code is long - I did not know how to make it shorter without loosing contexts.  The real code is a lot more involved.

Comments are in places of trouble.

The common parts:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


using ll = long long;

class Object    // Base class for an object that supports different sizes of members
{
public:
    Object() = default;
    virtual ~Object() = default;

    virtual ll GetId() = 0;
};

class ObjectV1 : public Object              // For this usage, this object will create ids 1 to 32767
{
public:
    ObjectV1() : id(++counter) {  }
    ~ObjectV1() override = default;

    ll GetId() override { return id; };
    /* v1 members . . . */
private:
    short id;   // 2 byte int
    static inline short counter{0};
};

class ObjectV2 : public Object              // For this usage, this object will create ids 200000 up
{
public:
    ObjectV2() : id(200000 + ++counter) {}
    ~ObjectV2() override = default;

    ll GetId() override { return id; }
private:
    ll id;  // 8 byte int
    static inline ll counter{0};
    /* v2 members . . . */
};
```

Original code using C pointers:

```
// Factory of Objects based on a key lookup
// Once the object for a given key is created, just return the cashed item
// In real life, the key determines which version of record to get - I translated to an int to simplify
class ObjectFactory_p
{
public:
    ObjectFactory_p() = default;
    ~ObjectFactory_p() noexcept { EmptyObjectCache(); };

    Object* GetObject(const std::string& key, int ver)
    {
        Object* pO{nullptr};
        auto it = objectCache.find(key);
        if (it == objectCache.end())
        {
            if (ver == 1)
                pO = new ObjectV1();
            else
                pO = new ObjectV2();

            if (pO)
            {
                //pO->Load();
                objectCache.emplace(key, pO);
            }
        }
        else pO = it->second;

        return pO;
    }

    void RemoveObjectFromCache(const std::string& key)
    {
        auto it = objectCache.find(key);
        if (it != objectCache.end())
        {
            delete it->second;
            objectCache.erase(it);
        }
    }

    inline void EmptyObjectCache()
    {
        for (const auto& [key, pO] : objectCache)
            delete pO;
        objectCache.clear();
    }

private:
    using ObjectMap = std::map<const std::string, Object*>;

    ObjectMap objectCache;
};  // ObjectFactory_p



void testing_p()
{
    ObjectFactory_p objectFactory;

    auto ov1 = objectFactory.GetObject("a-key-value-1", 1); // cacheSize = 1
    ll i1 = ov1->GetId();  std::cout << i1 << std::endl;    // = 1

    auto ov2 = objectFactory.GetObject("a-key-value-2", 2); // cacheSize = 2
    ll i2 = ov2->GetId();  std::cout << i2 << std::endl;    // = 200001

    auto ov3 = objectFactory.GetObject("a-key-value-1", 1); // cacheSize = 2
    ll i3 = ov3->GetId();  std::cout << i3 << std::endl;    // = 1

    auto ov4 = objectFactory.GetObject("a-key-value-3", 2); // cacheSize = 3
    ll i4 = ov4->GetId();  std::cout << i4 << std::endl;    // = 200002
}
```

Factory reworked with unique_ptr:

```
class ObjectFactory
{
public:
    ObjectFactory() = default;
    ~ObjectFactory() noexcept { EmptyObjectCache(); };

    std::unique_ptr<Object> GetObjectPtr(const std::string& key, int ver)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Object> upO;
        auto it = objectCache.find(key);
        if (it == objectCache.end())
        {
            if (ver == 1)
                upO = std::make_unique<ObjectV1>();
            else
                upO = std::make_unique<ObjectV2>();
            
            if (upO)
            {
                //upO->Load();
                objectCache.emplace(key, std::move(upO));
                // upO is now 'gone' so it can't be returned
            }
        }
        //else upO = it->second; // error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Object> &std::unique_ptr<Object>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<Object> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

        return upO;
    }

    Object& GetObjectRef(const std::string& key, int ver)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Object> upO;
        auto it = objectCache.find(key);
        if (it == objectCache.end())
        {
            if (ver == 1)
            {
                auto cit = objectCache.emplace(key, std::make_unique<ObjectV1>());
                //cit.first->second->Load();
                return *cit.first->second;
            }
            else
            {
                auto cit = objectCache.emplace(key, std::make_unique<ObjectV2>());
                //cit.first->second->Load();
                return *cit.first->second;
            }
        }
        else return *it->second;
    }

    void RemoveObjectFromCache(const std::string& key)
    {
        auto it = objectCache.find(key);
        if (it != objectCache.end())
        {
            it->second.reset();
            objectCache.erase(it);
        }
    }

    inline void EmptyObjectCache()
    {
        for (auto& [key, upO] : objectCache)
            upO.reset();
        objectCache.clear();
    }

private:
    using ObjectMap = std::map<const std::string, std::unique_ptr<Object>>;

    ObjectMap objectCache;
};  // ObjectFactory
```

Calling the objects:

```
// Same code as above but using std::unique_ptr instead of *
// It won't run because it gets back an empty object
void testing_SUP()
{
    ObjectFactory objectFactory;

    auto ov1 = objectFactory.GetObjectPtr("a-key-value-1", 1);  // shouldbe: // cacheSize = 1
    ll i1 = ov1->GetId();  std::cout << i1 << std::endl;        // shouldbe: // = 1

    auto ov2 = objectFactory.GetObjectPtr("a-key-value-2", 2);  // shouldbe: // cacheSize = 2
    ll i2 = ov2->GetId();  std::cout << i2 << std::endl;        // shouldbe: // = 200001

    auto ov3 = objectFactory.GetObjectPtr("a-key-value-1", 1);  // shouldbe: // cacheSize = 2
    ll i3 = ov3->GetId();  std::cout << i3 << std::endl;        // shouldbe: // = 1

    auto ov4 = objectFactory.GetObjectPtr("a-key-value-3", 2);  // shouldbe: // cacheSize = 3
    ll i4 = ov4->GetId();  std::cout << i4 << std::endl;        // shouldbe: // = 200002
}






// This one is using the return-by-ref but it then must revert to bad habits to make it into a C pointer again.
ll closer_to_the_real_code(const std::string& key)
{
    ObjectFactory objectFactory;

    Object* o;          // Since I need to try multiple times, this cannot be a ref - compiler wants it Init here

    o = &objectFactory.GetObjectRef(key, 2);            // Try to access v2 data
    if (!o)
        o = &objectFactory.GetObjectRef(key, 1);        // If fails, fall back to v1 data
    if (o)
        return o->GetId();
    return -1;
}





int main()
{
    testing_p();

    //testing_SUP();


    ll id = closer_to_the_real_code("a-key-value");
    std::cout << std::endl << id << std::endl;       // 200003

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Way too much code.  From your description is sounds like the cache should be holding a `std::shared_ptr` and handing out `std::weak_ptr`s.

Comment: You mention that your factory show own the objects, so why not simply continue returning pointers as before? Store `std::unique_ptr` in your cache and return raw pointers. Of course you might need to figure out a way to destroy objects, but that seems like a separate issue. An alternative is passing around `std::shared_ptr` (and `std::weak_ptr` in the cache), but then "everyone" owns the object...

Comment: Does the caller ever try to delete the object? If not you could continue returning a raw pointer, as long as you guarantee the cached object will out-live the caller's use of it.

Comment: If only the factory should *own* the pointer, then you should not be returning a `unique_ptr` but instead a raw pointer.  If the call site and the factory should *share* ownership, then you should us a `std::shared_ptr`.  There is nothing wrong with non-ownnig pointers, even in modern C++.  If you want to be more expressive, you can create a `observer_ptr ` type to express the returned pointer should no be deleted.

Comment: Thanks everyone.   I know it is a lot of code, but some of the issues I ran into were because I had two data types being stored.

For instance, I could not do `auto p = (ver=1) ? make_unique<V1>  :  make_unique<V2>;`

I have not used weak_ptr - I will have to study that one.

Comment: Yes, the factory class does all maintenance on the objects.  The user of it cleans up with `RemoveObjectFromCache()` and `EmptyObjectCache()`.

I had thought about return raw pointers - but that seemed anti-newstandards  :-)

Comment: I *did* think about the shared_ptrs after I posted and I got it working with those.

In ObjectV1 and ObjectV2, I added `using p = std::shared_ptr<ObjectV1>`
So now `p` can be changed to any type of pointer just by changing that :-)